# Larger organization – usage

Tags: word-usage, nuance

What would be the correct verbiage for referring to an outside organization?

For example:  “Your team provided an opportunity for this division to derive change within our *larger organization*”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "larger" refers to size, then use "enterprise." Knowing the size of the company by revenue further defines it as small enterprise, medium enterprise or large enterprise.

If larger means the "entire company" above "this division," then you could say one of the following:

- entire organization
- throughout the organization
- throughout the entire organization
- company wide
- throughout the company
- throughout the entire company

The following link includes classifications for organization size in the EU and USA:
[http://smbresearwch.net/sizing-up-smb/](http://smbresearch.net/sizing-up-smb/)